# Connect Python App to store data into Prometheus database

Tags: python, prometheus

I'm new to time series database and I'm trying to use Prometheus to store timeseries data so I can easily acces to Grafana if needed.

Now, I'm having difficult to understand how to link my python app that need to store datas to Prometheus.

My Prometheus database is deployed as Docker container with `docker run -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus` as explained in the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/).

Now, according to the [Prometheus Python client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python), I can store data as gauges with

```
from prometheus_client import Gauge
g = Gauge('my_inprogress_requests', 'Description of gauge')
g.inc()      # Increment by 1
g.dec(10)    # Decrement by given value
g.set(4.2)   # Set to a given value
```

On the client documentation it states that *"Metrics are usually exposed over HTTP, to be read by the Prometheus server."* And then *"To add Prometheus exposition to an existing HTTP server, see the `MetricsHandler` class which provides a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`."*

Unfortunately I can't find any other docs about using my existing Prometheus database server running on port 9090 of my localhost

Any help?